# audio noise reduction

Tags: audio

I have one doubt regarding audio processing for noise reduction. Is there any free ware and share ware DLLs available for noise reduction in .wav audio files or any sample codes using c#, vb.net or vb?

Comment: When you did a Google search what did you learn?

Comment: I didn't find any sample codes using c# or vb.net or vb

Comment: -1: Your comment makes no sense.  The first hit on Google is http://dotnetkicks.com/csharp/NoiseKiller_NET_C_application_for_noise_reduction.

Comment: i came across this link but I can't get the files, it was just a link going to http://gaech.blogspot.com/2006/09/noisekiller-01.html. If you have to check it first before you deduct!

Comment: @crisgomez: I asked.  You denied finding anything.  Yet there was something.  Your comment made no sense.  And -- since your question hasn't been updated to reflect new information -- your question and comments continue to make no sense.

Comment: do you understand my replied "I didn't find any SAMPLE CODES using c# or vb.net or vb " not a link- before commenting any non-sense try it first with you huh!

Comment: @crisgomez: "do you understand my replied".  Nope.  You didn't update the question to explain what was wrong with the first link.  Consequently all of the other users of Stack Overflow will have problems with this question also.  Please UPDATE the question to reflect what you didn't like about the first response from Google.  Please make the question (1) meaningful and (2) complete.

Comment: I have a "doubt" too - Where are people learning to say "doubt" when they mean "question"?  Is it a direct translation from some other language?  Are there scores of ESL teachers who are teaching this wrong somewhere?  Is it an common error from a web page translating site?  Where does this grammar mistake come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) is a cross-platform command-line application that does audio manipulation.  A quick check of the [man page](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) reveals that it can do noise reduction (see `noiseprof` and `noisered`).

You can use `trim` in combination with `noiseprof` to choose a small clip of a larger audio file to use as the noise.

Comment: hi BernzSed is there any library or sample codes using .net technology

Comment: No, but you can run other executables from c# using `Process.Start()`, from the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

Comment: ok thank you. I will try to create an application to use sox.thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

there are different meanings of "noise reduction". a simple implementation is a noise gate, which mutes the audio when the amplitude goes below a threshold. this is good enough for many applications. but a more sophist aced approach wouldcbe to do some frequency-domain analysis, w which is much less trivial. depending on your needs, the first approach is simple enough to roll your own. ymmv.