# Bulk MP3 noise removal

Tags: audio, automation, mp3, noise-reduction, audacity

### Overview:

I have about 1000 `MP3` files that I need to perform noise removal on.

I have used Audacity in the past for individual noise removal operations but Audacity will not cut it for this job.
Audacity is unable to perform bulk operations and I don't have the time to perform this manually on 1000s of `MP3` files.

### A little about the noise:

The noise is similar to white noise but it differs slightly in every `MP3` file, so a different noise profile will need to be built for each `MP3`.

The noise comes from a fan in the background (if you were wondering).

### Question:

What is the best way to automate nose removal from the `MP3` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/). It's a command line application so is scriptable. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331745/audio-noise-reduction) for further info.

Comment: I am going to test out the solution today. I have not had to to do so.

Comment: @PaddyD, from the docs in `http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html`, it seems that `noisered` presumably for noise-reduction is the function to use, but how do those *noise profiles* get built? Is there a command statement that allows the noise and signal files to be built in a single command?